# Publish WCF service witn my own Visual Studio Addin

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, add-in, wcf-data-services, visual-studio-addins

My Visual Studio Solution contains 2 main projects: ClickOnce application and WCF Service.

I have my own Visual Studio Addin, to publish my ClickOnce Application and now I want also to publish the WCF Service.

With this code I change the properties to configure the IIS paths:

```
Project clickOnceProj = GetProjectFromProjectName(MAIN_CLICKONCE_PROJECT_NAME);
Properties publishClickOnceProperties = (Properties) proj.Properties.Item("Publish").Value;
publishClickOnceProperties.Item("PublishUrl").Value = publishUrl;
publishClickOnceProperties.Item("InstallUrl").Value = installUrl;
publishClickOnceProperties.Item("UpdateUrl").Value = updateUrl;
clickOnceProj.Save();
```

And then I publish with this method:

```
public static bool CDCPUIEngine_Publish()
{
    SolutionBuild2 slnBuild2 = (SolutionBuild2)DTEUtilities.DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild;
    slnBuild2.Publish(true);
    bool buildDone = slnBuild2.BuildState == vsBuildState.vsBuildStateDone && slnBuild2.LastBuildInfo == 0;
    if (!buildDone) return false;
    return slnBuild2.PublishState == vsPublishState.vsPublishStateDone && slnBuild2.LastPublishInfo == 0;
}
```

In spite of I published using entire solution, this works fine and only publishes the two main projects, ClickOnce and WCF Serivce. The ClickOnce project has no errors and was published well, but WCF Service fails.

But if I publish the service manually and then I use my VisualStudio Addin, this works fine and is published in the folder it was configured last time (I checked that folder was recreated again using my Addin).

Could any help me and say me how can I change the Target location programatically in my Addin (I tried using Publish properties, like ClickOnce, but I can't because it is not accessible, I suppose because is not ClickOnce project).

In the next picure I show you the wizard with the properties I would like to be able to change programatically.

[Publish WCF Service wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UAy1.jpg)